# Error sending email. Address is missing domain

Tags: email, sendmail, dovecot

I am trying to install an email server on a VPS box, using the following programs:

```
Sendmail+Dovecot+Horde
```

Now, I believe all y configurations were correct. Yet, when trying to send emails from horde, I am getting the following error:

```
Address is missing domain
```

Also, this email box is not receiving any incoming email.

**Update** Versions:

```
sendmail-cf-8.14.7-4.el7.noarch
sendmail-8.14.7-4.el7.x86_64
dovecot-2.2.10-4.el7_0.1.x86_64
horde-groupware-5.2.1a
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit File: horde/imp/config/backends.php

```
set "disable" key to "true" in $servers['imap'] array.

set "disable" key to "false" in $servers['advanced'] array.
update 'maildomain' => 'YourDOMAIN'
```

Try and see if it works!